# Random effects structure lme

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I am seeking statistical advice on the random-effects structure of a mixed-model. I am using R's lme4 package.

Based on recent papers showing the importance of the random-effects structure  (such as http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749596X12001180), I would like to make sure that my random-structure is correct.

More specifically, I have predictors A and B and dependent variable Y.

Predictor A constitutes the experimental manipulation (every subject comes twice to the lab, undergoing treatment 1 or 2), and I have mulitple observations of the dependent variable Y (100 per participant, "ID"). B in contrast, is a nuisance variable (i.e., Hunger), which is assummed to be constant over the short time of the experiment.

Now I am not sure how to correctly specify the random effects if

a) I am interested (a priori) in the interaction between A and B. 
Would

```
summary(a<-glmer( Y ~ A * B + (1 + A*B|ID), data= x, family="binomial"), REML=FALSE)
```

or

```
summary(a<-glmer( Y ~ A * B + (1 + A|ID), data= x, family="binomial"), REML=FALSE)
```

be the correct model?

b) Assuming I am only interested in the main effect of A. B (e.g., hunger, or something that is constant over all experimental seesions, such as age) is considered a nuisance variable. 
Would

```
summary(a<-glmer( Y ~ A + B + (1 + A + B|ID), data= x, family="binomial"), REML=FALSE)
```

or

```
  summary(a<-glmer( Y ~ A + B + (1 + A|ID), data= x, family="binomial"), REML=FALSE)
```

be the correct model? Based on the post
[Mixed Model Analyses with Interactions in the Random Effects Structure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176300/mixed-model-analyses-with-interactions-in-the-random-effects-structure)
I would suggest the second, but please let me know if I am incorrect.

Thank you, Laura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your working hypotheses.

If you believe that the interaction between $A$ and $B$ will be the same for everybody (same additive effect on the log-odds ratio) then the second model (under (a)) is appropriate. If you believe it depends on the individual, then the first form is appropriate.

If I understand the question correctly, then you are saying $B$ is constant given ID and $A$. In that case, there's no point having `A*B|ID` in the model since that expands to `(A + B + A:B|ID)` and the last term has as many levels as there are data. The "random effects" would end up being a perfect fit for the individual means.

If $B$ is constant across *both* sessions then it should not appear in the random effect at all. In effect you would have no way to untangle which part of the random effect was down to $B$ and which down to `ID`. Thus the appropriate form would be `~1+A+B+(1+A|ID)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Indeed B is a constant given ID and A (in the first part of the question). So if you would not specify A*B|ID, what would you specify in that case? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming B has an ordinary effect and is different between sessions, `1+A+B+(1+A+B|ID)`. If B is the same at both sessions, then `1+A+B+(1+A|ID)`.